# Erro SELECT mysqli por data

Tags: php, mysqli

Bom dia pessoal, tudo bom? O problema é o seguinte. Coloquei para o usuário digital a data inicial e final para busca de um determinado resultado no banco de dados. 
O Código é esse:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM pontocolaborador WHERE cpfColaborador = '$aba' AND dataPonto >= '$inicial' AND dataPonto <= '$final' ORDER BY dataPonto ASC");
```

Entretanto, quando eu digito por exemplo: Data inicial 01/10/2019 a 31/10/2019, ele acaba puxando também a data 01/11/2019 à 04/11/2019 que no caso está entre o período digital. Porém, eu não puxei a data do mês 10 e sim do mês 11. Pergunta: Existe alguma possibilidade de barrar isso? Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrescente a função DATE do SQL para os campos de data, principalmente se os campos de data estiverem definidos como DATETIME.

Código:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM pontocolaborador WHERE cpfColaborador = '$aba' AND DATE(dataPonto) >= '{$inicial}' AND DATE(dataPonto) <= '{$final}' ORDER BY dataPonto ASC"

$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $SQL);
```

Uma dica que sugiro a você é construir sua query e testar no seu SGBD para garantir que funcione e depois passar para o PHP